# Android in app billing version 2 multiple restore

Tags: android, in-app-billing, restore

I am implementing in-appbilling  version 2 in android,  I want to  restore multiple products but I am not sure that how to get the list of all the products which are purchased,  **for your reference i am using managed type  and cant use version 3**

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this method

```
BillingService mBillingService = new BillingService();
mBillingService.setContext(this);
mBillingService.restoreTransactions();
```

And this method will call many different methods one by one and there is one method called **purchaseResponse() inside file ResponseHandler.java**

```
public static void purchaseResponse(final Context context,
            final PurchaseState purchaseState, final String productId,
            final String orderId, final long purchaseTime,
            final String developerPayload, final String purchaseToken) {
```

Inside this method you will get all product details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to test it first with a sample app. Here is how you can test it.This will take care of your restoring problem once look at below sample app properly

**Step 1.** Install the sample app -[TrivialDrive](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample)

**Step 2.** Now test with Static Responses: there are 4 buttons on Mainactivity replace the button item code with these reserved product IDs.

- android.test.purchased
- android.test.canceled
- android.test.refunded
- android.test.item_unavailable

For using these reserved product IDs you dont have to add items in your developers console application
Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) for testing your app

Once you have tested with above method, you are ready to test with your own product, Here is a detail turorial link to do that 
[Testing In-app Purchases Using Your Own Product IDs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real)

Also try sample app- [DungeonsRedux](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/tree/master/DungeonsRedux)